# CVPixelBufferRef CVImageBufferRef bytesPerRow is wrong?

Tags: avfoundation

so i have code that reads from an AVAsset using kCVPixelFormat_32BGRA. I get the next sample buffer by calling

```
[vidInput copyNextSamplebuffer];
```

Then I proceed with Apple's code on their AVFoundation guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW4

What troubles me is that sometimes

```
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
```

gives me something that isnt the width*4, and as a result, when I attempt to use it, the image is teared very badly. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: The bytes per row might be padded out to be divisible by 16. Is that a problem?

Comment: i doubt that. the dimensions are 568 x 320. if you take any of the two and multiply by 4, the result will be divisible by 16.

Comment: In any case rowbytes doesn't have to be 4*width - that's why rowbytes exists.

Comment: it doesn't have to be, but i specified that it takes it in as 32BGRA, which means every pixel is 32bits, or 4 bytes, and hence row per bytes should be 4*width.

Comment: Nuhuh, AVAssetReader is free to choose any rowbytes it likes as long as rowbytes >= pixelSize*width. This implementation is a classic example of a memory/speed tradeoff. In any case, you'll have to deal with. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rhythmic was spot on - if you want to look at another question this is discussed (in more detail): [iOS CVImageBuffer distorted from AVCaptureSessionDataOutput with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540710/ios-cvimagebuffer-distorted-from-avcapturesessiondataoutput-with-avcapturesessio)

Comment: Could you please look at this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489426/how-is-cvpixelbufferbytesperrow-calculated