# Updating only a horizontal subregion of a texture in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This question is specific to OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android, but there may be work-arounds that use common GL functionality so I'm tagging this as "opengl".

tl;dr: is there another way to specify `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH)` in OpenGL ES 2.0?  Because according to the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/), the `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` doesn't exist in OpenGL ES 2.0.

I have a texture that I update frequently by calling `glTexImage2D`, from a fixed region of client memory that is being updated independently.  In some cases I know only a subregion of the image has changed.  I can limit the number of *rows* that are updated by calling `glTexSubImage2d` and specifying only the top half of the texture (for example).  This results in significant performance improvement.

But when I tried to also limit the number of columns updated (say I want to update only the upper-*left* quadrant of the texture), I noticed that there is no **stride** parameter to `glTexSubImage2d`.  Since for my application the area of client memory that is the source for all `glTexImage2d`/`glTexSubImage2d` has the full width of the image, I need to specify that as the stride if I call `glTexSubImage2d`.

`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH,stride)` seems to be the way to do this, but `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` isn't supported in OpenGL 2.0 ES.  So is there a way to update a horizontal subregion of a texture in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: By the way, even if updating the whole texture you should still use `glTexSubImage2D` instead of `glTexImage2D` (provided your texture is already properly sized), since the latter will allocate the whole texture anew while the former will just update its data. It may be your performance improvement when using `glTexSubImage2D` comes partly from this fact rather than the fact that you're only updating a sub-region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenGL ES 2.0? Nope. There's [an extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_unpack_subimage.txt) for it though; I have no idea how widely implemented it is. And ES 3.0 has full support for it.

Comment: OK, thanks Nicol.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something since I'm new to OpenGL.