# ScreenCaptureKit/CVPixelBuffer format yields unexpected results

Tags: swift, cgimage, cvpixelbuffer, screencapturekit

I have a project where I use ScreenCaptureKit. For various reasons out of the scope of the question, the format that I configure ScreenCaptureKit to use is `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` -- I need the raw BGRA data, which gets manipulated later on.

When I construct a `CGImage` or `NSImage` from the data, displays and *some* windows look fine (*full code included at the bottom of the question -- this is just an excerpt of the conversion*).

```
guard let cvPixelBuffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer else { return }
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, .readOnly)
defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, .readOnly) }
let vImageBuffer: vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer),
                                                        height: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvPixelBuffer)),
                                                        width: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixelBuffer)),
                                                        rowBytes: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixelBuffer) * 4)
        
let cgImageFormat: vImage_CGImageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
                    bitsPerComponent: 8,
                    bitsPerPixel: 32,
                    colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                    bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue),
                    renderingIntent: .defaultIntent
                )!
if let cgImage: CGImage = try? vImageBuffer.createCGImage(format: cgImageFormat) {
  let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: .init(width: CGFloat(cgImage.width), height: CGFloat(cgImage.height)))
  Task { @MainActor in
    self.image = nsImage
  }
}
```

The resulting image for displays looks reasonable (except for incorrect color, since the incoming data is BGRA and the CGImage expects RGBA -- that's dealt with elsewhere in my project).

[image]

However, *some* windows (not all) get a very odd distortion and tearing effect. Here's Calendar.app for example:

[image]

Here is Mail.app, which is *less* broken:

[image]

As far as I can tell, the formats of the `CVPixelBuffer` are the same in each case. When I inspect the `CVPixelBuffer` using the debugger (instead of doing the conversion to `CGImage`/`NSImage`) the `CVPixelBuffer` displays perfectly in QuickLook, so it's not that the actual data is damaged either -- there's just something about the format I don't understand.

### Question:

How can I get the RGBA data reliably from these windows in the same way that it is *always* returned for displays?

---

#### Full, runnable sample code:

```
class ScreenCaptureManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var availableWindows: [SCWindow] = []
    @Published var availableDisplays: [SCDisplay] = []
    @Published var image: NSImage?
    private var stream: SCStream?
    private let videoSampleBufferQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.sample.VideoSampleBufferQueue")
    
    func getAvailableContent() {
        Task { @MainActor in
            do {
                let availableContent: SCShareableContent = try await SCShareableContent.excludingDesktopWindows(true,
                                                                                                                onScreenWindowsOnly: true)
                self.availableWindows = availableContent.windows
                self.availableDisplays = availableContent.displays
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func basicStreamConfig() -> SCStreamConfiguration {
        let streamConfig = SCStreamConfiguration()
        streamConfig.minimumFrameInterval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 5)
        streamConfig.showsCursor = true
        streamConfig.queueDepth = 5
        streamConfig.pixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA
        return streamConfig
    }
    
    func startCaptureForDisplay(display: SCDisplay) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            try? await stream?.stopCapture()
            let filter = SCContentFilter(display: display, including: availableWindows)
            let streamConfig = basicStreamConfig()
            streamConfig.width = Int(display.frame.width * 2)
            streamConfig.height = Int(display.frame.height * 2)
            stream = SCStream(filter: filter, configuration: streamConfig, delegate: self)
            do {
                try stream?.addStreamOutput(self, type: .screen, sampleHandlerQueue: videoSampleBufferQueue)
                try await stream?.startCapture()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: ", error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startCaptureForWindow(window: SCWindow) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            try? await stream?.stopCapture()
            let filter = SCContentFilter(desktopIndependentWindow: window)
            let streamConfig = basicStreamConfig()
            streamConfig.width = Int(window.frame.width * 2)
            streamConfig.height = Int(window.frame.height * 2)
            
            stream = SCStream(filter: filter, configuration: streamConfig, delegate: self)
            do {
                try stream?.addStreamOutput(self, type: .screen, sampleHandlerQueue: videoSampleBufferQueue)
                try await stream?.startCapture()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ScreenCaptureManager: SCStreamOutput, SCStreamDelegate {
    func stream(_: SCStream, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, of _: SCStreamOutputType) {
        guard let cvPixelBuffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer else { return }
        
        print("PixelBuffer", cvPixelBuffer)
        
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, .readOnly)

        defer {
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        }
        
        let vImageBuffer: vImage_Buffer = vImage_Buffer(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvPixelBuffer),
                                                        height: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvPixelBuffer)),
                                                        width: vImagePixelCount(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixelBuffer)),
                                                        rowBytes: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixelBuffer) * 4)
        
        let cgImageFormat: vImage_CGImageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
                    bitsPerComponent: 8,
                    bitsPerPixel: 32,
                    colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                    bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.last.rawValue),
                    renderingIntent: .defaultIntent
                )!
        if let cgImage: CGImage = try? vImageBuffer.createCGImage(format: cgImageFormat) {
            let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: .init(width: CGFloat(cgImage.width), height: CGFloat(cgImage.height)))
            Task { @MainActor in
                self.image = nsImage
            }
        }
    }

    func stream(_: SCStream, didStopWithError error: Error) {
        print("JN: Stream error", error)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var screenCaptureManager = ScreenCaptureManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(screenCaptureManager.availableDisplays, id: \.displayID) { display in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Display: \(display.width) x \(display.height)")
                    }.frame(height: 60).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).border(Color.black).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        screenCaptureManager.startCaptureForDisplay(display: display)
                    }
                }
                ForEach(screenCaptureManager.availableWindows.filter { $0.title != nil && !$0.title!.isEmpty }, id: \.windowID) { window in
                    HStack {
                        Text(window.title!)
                    }.frame(height: 60).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).border(Color.black).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        screenCaptureManager.startCaptureForWindow(window: window)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 200)
            Divider()
            
            if let image = screenCaptureManager.image {
                Image(nsImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 800, height: 600, alignment: .leading)
        .onAppear {
            screenCaptureManager.getAvailableContent()
        }
    }
}
```

(*Note: I know that displaying an NSImage of the captured content is not the most efficient method of previewing the content -- it's merely for showing the issue here*)

Comment: Update: it looks like it has something to do with `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow` not matching what I expect...

Comment: It looks like there are 72 more bytes per row than I would expect given the height and width of the image. Perhaps that has to do with this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1829/_index.html But, then I'm a bit at a loss for how to use some of the Accelerate vector operations to manipulate the image.

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540710/ios-cvimagebuffer-distorted-from-avcapturesessiondataoutput-with-avcapturesessio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScreenCaptureKit can return `CVPixelBuffer`s (via `CMSampleBuffer`) that have padding bytes on the end of each row. The problem line of my code was:

```
rowBytes: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvPixelBuffer) * 4
```

This line made the assumption that the `rowBytes` would be the width of the image, multiplied by 4, since in RGBA formats, there are four bytes per pixel.

This line should have been:

```
rowBytes: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvPixelBuffer)
```

This value can vary based on hardware as described in: [Technical Q&A QA1829](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1829/_index.html)

It seems that having a hardware aligned `rowBytes` parameter allows some efficiencies when moving the information around quickly on a local machine. However, when moving the data elsewhere (over a network, for example), most often the destination will expect the extra bytes to *not* appear in the data, meaning that you have to copy the rows *without* the extra padding bytes before transferring the data.